# How to close alert pop up window in Katalon extension?

Tags: katalon-studio

Please, check the below link. How to close this:

https://www.screencast.com/t/hOwFbLRD6q

Comment: If is it an Javascript alert, use WebUI.acceptAlert(). If not, please share your pages HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an `AutoIT` script for this purpose or simply use `java.awt.Robot` class to send an ENTER.

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.delay(3000);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```